# Complexity analysis of nested recursive functions

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

I've written out a recursive algorithm for a little homegrown computer algebra system, where I'm applying pairwise reductions to the list of operands of an algebraic operation (adjacent operands only, as the algebra is non-commutative). I'm trying to get an idea of the runtime complexity of my algorithm (but unfortunately, as a physicist it's been a very long time since I took any undergrad CS courses that dealt with complexity analysis). Without going into details of the specific problem, I think I can formalize the algorithm in terms of a function `f` that is a "divide" step and a function `g` that combines the results. My algorithm would then take the following formal representation:

```
f(1) = 1  # recursion anchor for f
f(n) = g(f(n/2), f(n/2))

g(n, 0) = n, g(0, m) = m            # recursion ...
g(1, 0) = g(0, 1) = 1               # ... anchors for g

           / g(g(n-1, 1), m-1)  if reduction is "non-neutral"
g(n, m) = |  g(n-1, m-1)        if reduction is "neutral"
           \ n + m              if no reduction is possible
```

In this notation, the functions `f` and `g` receive lists as arguments and return lists, with the *length* of the input/output lists being the argument and the right-hand-side of the equations above.

For the full story, the actual code corresponding to `f` and `g` is the following:

```
def _match_replace_binary(cls, ops: list) -> list:
    """Reduce list of `ops`"""
    n = len(ops)
    if n <= 1:
        return ops
    ops_left = ops[:n//2]
    ops_right = ops[n//2:]
    return _match_replace_binary_combine(
            cls,
            _match_replace_binary(cls, ops_left),
            _match_replace_binary(cls, ops_right))


def _match_replace_binary_combine(cls, a: list, b: list) -> list:
    """combine two fully reduced lists a, b"""
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return a + b
    if len(a) == 1 and len(b) == 1:
        return a + b
    r = _get_binary_replacement(a[-1], b[0], cls._binary_rules)
    if r is None:
        return a + b
    if r == cls.neutral_element:
        return _match_replace_binary_combine(cls, a[:-1], b[1:])
    r = [r, ]
    return _match_replace_binary_combine(
            cls,
            _match_replace_binary_combine(cls, a[:-1], r),
            b[1:])
```

I'm interested in the worst-case number of times `get_binary_replacement` is
called, depending on the size of `ops`

Comment: Have you tried to apply the _Master Theorem_? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master-Theorem

Comment: I knew there had to be a theorem about this! From a first glance, it seems to apply exactly to my situation, I'll read through the details and see where that gets me

Comment: @macmoonshine I don't think the Master theorem can be applied directly. It deals with the recursions of the type `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`, however the OP problem is of the type `T(n) = g(T(n/b), T(n/c)) + f(n)` and I don't see an easy way to reduce this to the first form... In any case the first thing to do is to get the complexity of `g`, since it does not depend on `f`. After that you just replace the two arguments in that complexity with `f(n/2)` and after this you may end up in the form of the Master theorem, assuming it remains linear...

Comment: In any case I think I have bad news for you Michael. Your `g` function seems [a variation over the Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) which is a computable function that grows more than any primitive recursive function... in other words you can hope to compute it *only* with *extremely* small arguments... in other words: the complexity of `g` is bigger than any: polynomial, exponential and even *tower of exponentials*!

Comment: @Bakuriu At first glance it does look like a variation of Ackermann, but it's not (mainly because the condition does not depend on the arguments): there is a worst case of `g`, namely the "non-neutral" case, so I think we can actually use that. If I code up the function `g` (using "non-neutral' always and call `g(n, m)`, the resulting number of calls is always `2*(n+m)-1`, so that insight should help me a lot in the analysis!

Comment: @MichaelGoerz you are lucky then! Good for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I've got it now. To restate the problem: find the number of calls to `_get_binary_replacement` when calling `_match_replace_binary` with an input of size `n`.

- define function `g(n, m)` (as in original question) that maps the size of the the two inputs of `_match_replace_binary_combine` to the size of the output
- define a function `T_g(n, m)` that maps the size of the two inputs of `_match_replace_binary_combine` to the total number of calls to `g` that is required to obtain the result. This is also the (worst case) number of calls to `_get_binary_replacement` as each call to `_match_replace_binary_combine` calls `_get_binary_replacement` at most once

We can now consider the worst case and best case for `g`:

- **best case** (no reduction): `g(n,m) = n + m`, `T_g(n, m) = 1`
- **worst case** (all non-neutral reduction): `g(n, m) = 1`, `T_g(n, m) = 2*(n+m) - 1` (I determined this empirically)

Now, the [*master theorem* (WP)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) applies:

Going through the description on WP:

- `k=1` (the recursion anchor is for size 1)
- We split into `a = 2` subproblems of size `n/2` in constant (`d = 1`) time
- After solving the subproblems, the amount of work required to combine the results is `c = T_g(n/2, n/2)`. This is `n-1` (approximately `n`) in the worst case and 1 in the best case

Thus, following the examples on the WP page for the master theorem, the worst case complexity is `n * log(n)`, and the best case complexity is `n`

Empirical trials  seem to bear out this result. Any objections to my line of reasoning?